# Nginx PHP-FPM stops working, and an open socket is left in the connection

Tags: php, nginx

I have this reoccurring issue with Nginx about once a day, about twice under high traffic loads. The fix is easy: Restart the server, but when the error happens, Nginx completely stops working. I have an Nginx [PHP-FPM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP#Installation_and_configuration) setup.

It issue starts with:

```
020/09/27 09:57:27 [error] 38#38: *430982 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while connecting to upstream, client: x.x.x.x, server: example.com, request: "POST /api/sessions/wri
```

And then it progress into:

```
2020/09/27 10:03:22 [alert] 40#40: *431277 open socket #18 left in connection 51
2020/09/27 10:03:22 [alert] 38#38: *431298 open socket #34 left in connection 166
2020/09/27 10:03:22 [alert] 40#40: *431288 open socket #28 left in connection 59
2020/09/27 10:03:22 [alert] 38#38: *431296 open socket #32 left in connection 169
2020/09/27 10:03:22 [alert] 38#38: *431257 open socket #36 left in connection 177
2020/09/27 10:03:22 [alert] 38#38: *431291 open socket #23 left in connection 178
2020/09/27 10:03:22 [alert] 38#38: *431253 open socket #27 left in connection 188
2020/09/27 10:03:22 [alert] 38#38: *431300 open socket #31 left in connection 197
2020/09/27 10:03:22 [alert] 38#38: *431312 open socket #12 left in connection 204
2020/09/27 10:03:22 [alert] 38#38: *431259 open socket #38 left in connection 206
2020/09/27 10:03:22 [alert] 37#37: aborting
2020/09/27 10:03:22 [alert] 38#38: aborting
2020/09/27 10:03:22 [alert] 40#40: aborting
2020/09/27 10:03:23 [warn] 21568#21568: 8096 worker_connections exceed open file resource limit: 1024
    2020/09/27 10:08:24 [warn] 21574#21574: *636 upstream server temporarily disabled while connecting to upstream,
```

Now [GET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods) requests still do work. So if I go to the website, it loads. But anything that is [POST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_%28HTTP%29), [PUT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods) or [DELETE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods) will fail, so ultimately the users can’t do anything but browse.

Why is this happening? And is there a health check that can be used to detect these issues?

Comment: You should try increasing the Request Timeout in NGINX.

Comment: @Md.MirajKhan, this may help, but it is fix for the symtoms, not the cause of a problem.

Comment: *All* the answers are late answers (2021 till 2023 (today)). What is your assessment of them?

Comment: Hi Devin, Did you able to fix this? I am also getting the same issue.

Comment: What weird is this no longer happens in GCP. I switch providers, use the same docker image, and problem is gone. I think its something to do with AWS.

Answer (score 1):

About the first timeout error you see, if you are using a [FastCGI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FastCGI) configuration, then you might need to review this:

```
fastcgi_read_timeout 600s;
```

Make sure that value is longer than the longest processing PHP will be doing.

You should also definitely increase worker connections setting to whatever expected number of simultaneous connections you expect (say 10000):

```
worker_connections 10000;
```

Also, as mentioned by [Sang Lu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64087436/nginx-php-fpm-stops-working-and-an-open-socket-is-left-in-the-connection/70516750#70516750), you need to make sure nginx can open enough file handles (which includes network sockets as well).

If you start the master nginx process as root, you can simply do (at least two times of the `worker_connections` configuration above:

```
worker_rlimit_nofile 21000;
```

The other way is to use `ulimit` or `/etc/security/limits.conf` for the user that starts the master nginx process.

Answer (score 0):

Probably it is that your Nginx process is opening too many files. You can increase this limit by following this article: [How to Increase Number of Open Files Limit in Linux](https://www.tecmint.com/increase-set-open-file-limits-in-linux/)

To change this setting, you need the root privilege and do as follows:

1. Open the */etc/security/limits.conf* file: `vi /etc/security/limits.conf`
2. Append those lines at the end of the file:

   ```
   ## Example hard limit for maximum number of opened files
   *    hard    nofile    10240
   ## Example soft limit for maximum number of opened files
   *    soft    nofile    10240
   ```
3. Save all changes and **Reboot** your Server/VPS to apply new settings.

**Note**: The number **10240** is the maximum number of files that a process can open. Change this value as your needs.

Comment: It doesn't look for me, that the root cause is the number of opened files, because the first message is about timeout. So I think that nginx ends up with a lot of files because the upstream (PHP-FPM in our case) is clogged, and can't handle requests within reasonable time. I would try to play around with the PHP-FPM workers settings: maybe add more processes, or change the whole process-spawning mode. See this article for PHP-FPM settings: https://tideways.com/profiler/blog/an-introduction-to-php-fpm-tuning

Answer (score -3):

Here are a few steps you can take to diagnose and resolve the issue:

1. Increasing PHP-FPM timeouts requires changing the `request_terminate_timeout`, `request_slowlog_timeout, and` max_execution_time`settings in your PHP-FPM configuration file (often located at`/etc/php-fpm.conf`or`/etc/php/version/fpm/php-fpm.conf)`. Once the changes have been made, restart PHP-FPM.
2. **Increase Nginx timeouts:** In your Nginx configuration file (usually located at `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` or `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf`), adjust the `proxy_read_timeout` and `fastcgi_read_timeout` values to allow for longer request processing times. Restart Nginx after making the changes.
3. **Verify the server's resources:** Keep an eye on the server's resource utilization during periods of high traffic. Check to see if your CPU, memory, and disk I/O are not running out of space. If required, think about updating your server or streamlining the code and database queries in your application to boost performance.
4. Enable the PHP-FPM slow log to find any sluggish requests that can be the reason for the timeouts. Uncomment the'slowlog' directive and set its value to the directory where you wish to store the log file in your PHP-FPM configuration file. Once the changes have been made, restart PHP-FPM. Look for any bottlenecks in your application code by analyzing the log file.
5. **Implement health checks:** To run routine health checks on your Nginx and PHP-FPM servers, you can set up a monitoring system or use third-party tools. These checks can assist in finding any problems before they impair service. The server's response time, CPU use, memory utilization, and other pertinent data can all be observed.
6. **Enable error logging:** Ensure that **PHP-FPM and Nginx** error logging are both turned on. Look through the error logs for any pertinent error messages that can offer more information about the reason for the timeouts.

Comment: Looks like ChatGPT

Comment: What is that? Obfuscation?