# Debugging Nginx Dump

Tags: php, nginx

In a previous post, I talked about an issue where nginx PUT, POST, DELETE suddenly stopping working, and the only way to fix is to restart Nginx. It was this here:

[Nginx PHP-FPM Stops Working, open socket left in connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64087436/nginx-php-fpm-stops-working-open-socket-left-in-connection)

In my nginx config, I added the following:

worker_rlimit_core  500M;
working_directory /tmp;
debug_points abort;

This dumps the core on restart with messages that happened as the error occur. Also my nginx version is:

```
    nginx version: nginx/1.14.2
built with OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --with-cc-opt='-g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/nginx-Cjs4TR/nginx-1.14.2=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2' --with-ld-opt='-Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -fPIC' --prefix=/usr/share/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --lock-path=/var/lock/nginx.lock --pid-path=/run/nginx.pid --modules-path=/usr/lib/nginx/modules --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/body --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/fastcgi --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/proxy --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/scgi --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/uwsgi --with-debug --with-pcre-jit --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_auth_request_module --with-http_v2_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_slice_module --with-threads --with-http_addition_module --with-http_geoip_module=dynamic --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_image_filter_module=dynamic --with-http_sub_module --with-http_xslt_module=dynamic --with-stream=dynamic --with-stream_ssl_module --with-stream_ssl_preread_module --with-mail=dynamic --with-mail_ssl_module --add-dynamic-module=/build/nginx-Cjs4TR/nginx-1.14.2/debian/modules/http-auth-pam --add-dynamic-module=/build/nginx-Cjs4TR/nginx-1.14.2/debian/modules/http-dav-ext --add-dynamic-module=/build/nginx-Cjs4TR/nginx-1.14.2/debian/modules/http-echo --add-dynamic-module=/build/nginx-Cjs4TR/nginx-1.14.2/debian/modules/http-upstream-fair --add-dynamic-module=/build/nginx-Cjs4TR/nginx-1.14.2/debian/modules/http-subs-filter
```

Here is what my core dumped.

```
?x^5i? ?Pr[?/VP?\(?x??W[?/VPr[?/V????x^5i????? Z5i?x^5i?       ??4?4@??@P?F?F`??r??Pn|w%????????%?S??P?[?/V@?[?/V$??p?`?[?/VnR5i?`R5i?`R5i?cZ5i?SZ5i??i5i?????api   examplecom?P5i???????P5i?pR5i?????PT5i??^`?[?/Vq)??`?r?%?^??Hk?C??\OZ5i?P?\(?x?{>?? Z5i??T5i??(@????U5i?Pe5i?d??????Pr[?/V$?W[?/V?g5i??g5i?`i5i?hi5i?`?[?/V@x5i?@ELF>?C@?c@8api exampllecom?4?4P?\(?x?@Pr[?/V?!C?       ????
??(???\??$??*bc?m?*0X??E?ZHa?F?`?6?T?\_̠ߓ?#???e?A?x?1?5)?m
                                                         ??\?Ԅzm?S??B?????  ??????9???FCr?xx"?IE??8Xڷi'Bv??Q????'?G'&??$??1'?mf
         C?~??4?????CIC?!C?d ??y??2??=????i??8?NW?l^???c??A?I?z???P????f?2???^*??h?Z~~??Ds
?V??c_??TF?>? 1????????????j!??????;?   ??`?๷6?H,?>?
                                                    ?????t6?K???)[ۓ֡????$?o???????u?i?Լ"????Ej,???^?U??@C?Z?
                                                                                                           ?3G?&f?jF??)??ä?ҩ}????!`?T??@ ??
                 Η?D??;`
                        ?{?R???ŷ??Td?W?f<?Y??q??3???_C?4>x?h?vC?@?i?/V@?i?/V????/V?i?/V???/V?i?/V??\?/VaC??i?/????/V8A???\[5i?`8t??c5i??\5i?`8t?/V`8t?/V??U?Y5ip???~[?/V?X5i?Y5i??????Z5i??^Y5i? Z5i??X5i??MC??X5i??_C? h?vC?@?i?/V@?i?/V?~?/V?i?/V?~?/V?i?/V?k?/VaC??i?/V?~?/V8A?(?k?/V?k?/V? t?/V?Z5i??e5i??\5i??/[??\5i?@e5i?_^5i?`8t?/V`8t?/V??U??Z5i??p??[?/V0?r??
                                                                                                                   ?
                                                                                                                   ?[5i?@8?p??!8i?^P?[?/V??????p?^????P?[?/V??5??[5i?X@`@????????X:??X@
6?0?i?/V??5?X)t?/)t?/V???(n5i?S6?P?\(?x??c5i?w?Z??]5i?? t?/V?c5i??]5i??]5i??[??h]5i????/?]5i?(n5i??]5i??c5i??]5i?
                                                                                                               N5????/VX@?<W?@?W?
       M5??<W?@?W??ϗ?/Vp???/Vp?J?P?\(?xn??/VP?\(?x?@???/n??/V@???/V??W?`_5in??/V??J?`_5i???W?`N5?t??/V?h?/VpU?P?\(?x?197P?\(?x???W?????????Eo?/VH?\?/Vp?\?/V\?/V@$u?/V????/V????/V?t?/V0`5i?P_5i?P?\(?x??ki?/V4?B???^5i??AW?P?\(?x?p0u?/V?  ?/Vp0u?/V@$u?/V?+   ?/VP?\(?x?????/Vh?\?/Vp?\?/V@$u?/V????/Vx?/V>W??v]?/?\?/VP`5i?
                                                                              M5?8?i?/V ?W?>W?0???/VP?\(?x?`???/VR??/V1Z?/???/VP?\(?x?h?W?8?i?/V0c5i??l5i?0c5i??55??l5i?8?i?/V?????4?0^???/V8?i?/VP?\(?x?0c5i?h?W?8?i?/V0c5i??l5i?h?W?I85? ???/VPH}?/V????5??/V?????????b5i????r?/V?b5i??b5i??̭?mf5i?PH}?/Vr?/Vc5i??@?n}?/V??+?/V???/V?@?/V????/Vp???p??????/V?"\?/V?c5i????x???/V?c5i??c5i??í?d?c5i?@????/V???/V?q?/V
????/Vs???/V 0Pm5i?`l5i?2020/09/30 06:22:57 [error] 36#36: *109165 no live upstreams while connecting to upstream, client: 10.0.1.91, server: api.example.com, request: "POST /api/screeningchatusers/syncaccount?_key=MTAwY2Q1YTA4MTM3NzI3MmFjZGE1Njk4ZWM3ZDdkYzM4YzAwOWFjNg%3D%3D&_sig=MGU3ZjRhZDFjMDUwZmJkOWM2NjNlMDk1YTE3MWY4ZDgzYzQwYTNlNg%3D%3D HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://api.example.com//screeningchatusers/syncaccountHg5i?Aw2????????I3MmFjZG0m5i?@m5i????????ZmJkOWM2????/Vp???e>?pn5i??f5i??ɭ?????h5i?`??????ug5i??ɭ?????????5?s0Po5i??8??h?/V??m??h?/V36/VP?\(?x?"?36/VP?\(?x?q5i?Eo?/V?h5i?i5i?q5?[?/Vi5i?v?/V(0?h5i?h5i?P?\(?x?00$$$$Neg?/V?j5i??109172P?\(?x?`q5i??p5i?Eo?/V:44 [err?h5i?i5i?q5i?[?/Vi5i??+?/VAi5i?#i5i?,i5i????/V?q5i? 0r5i?q5i?2020/09/30 06:23:54 [alert] 36#36: aborting
eft in connection 72
Eo?/V????/V????/V?Kk?/V
                       ?t?/V0pj5i??i5i?P?\(?x?????/V????/VP(?g5i?172.17.0.2?????????S??M3YWEyODPj5i?P?\(?x?????/VP?\(?x???*????/V&,p????ɭ?Y/Vc/xY?/V2a0dP?\(?x?????????????????Eo?/VP?\(?x?
?/VPk5i?p???P?\(?x?????/V?ė?/VPp5i?????/V?k5i??ė?/V~m
?/V????/V?k5i??ė?/V8???/V?×?/VP?\(?x?ė?/V????/V?q?/VPp5i?????/V????/VL?
?/V??/VP?\(?x??l5i?????/VP?\(?x??×?/V??/VPp5i???/V????/V????/V??
?/Vp?k?/VP?\(?x???/V?×?/V??/VP?\(?x?@m5i?@m5i?pn5i???Y?/V??/Vz$t_8??3????????Y?/V??Y?/V??Y?/V??Y?/V??Y?/V??Y?/V??Y?/V??Y?/V?????3
       ?/V??/Vt???/VP?\(?x???????????/V????/V????/V?×?/V????/V`??P?\(?x? ?f?/VP?\(?x???/V??Y?/V?o5i?????????????0Po5i??n5i?P?\(?x?Eo?/Vno5i?to5i?po5i?to5i?????/Vpŗ?/Vpŗ?/V?t?/V0?o5i?o5i?P?\(?x?????/V?h?/V*?h?/V2050??h?/V2054?????????54P?\(?x?ro5i?????????Eo?/V??/V??/V??/V???/V??/V??/V?t?/V00?p5i??o5i?P?\(?x????/V????/V?p5i??p5i??p5i?????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????p5i?P?\(?x?&??55?? p???P?\(?x????????Р???[?/V???/VX???
                              ??/VВ???????[?/V&???[?/VP?\(?x????/V?/Vh??/V?[?/V ??/Vx$?/V?[?/V"??/V???????????/Ví?/V?#?/V???/??/VP?\(?x??[?/V?[?/?r5i????????????/Vп?/V?[?/V#   P?\(?x??[?/V???/V??k?/VT??/?[?/Vps5i???/V???/V?s5i??[?/u?[?/VP?\(?x?33
?/V?[?/V?[?/V??/V??/V???/V?[?/V??/Vu5i?p???/V?t5i???Y?/V???/V
                                                             ??/V

                                                                 ??/V???/VP?\(?x?0q?p??/V?/V@x5i??P??Xx5i?Hx5i? ?/Vgq.??Ұ??/V@x5i?gq.????gqh?-E?Xx5i???r?vq??/V@x5i?*?/V8x5i??~5i??|[?/V?|[?/V?|[?/V?|[?/V
}[?/V}[?/V}[?/V^}[?/Vj}[?/Vp}[?/V~}[?/V?}[?/V?}[?/V?}[?/V?}[?/V?}[?/V?}[?/V?}[?/V! 8i????d@??/V8
                                                                                                p?      ?/V

9z5i??5i?Iz5i?  P?\(?x?g?x????8x86_64nginx: worker process is shutting down/usr/sbin/nginxELF>` @?@8@??HH???<<P?td???<<
???x?|?Cn?*?&&?bemX?"?
                      

?"
?*0
  1"

     
T??6
     *="
D?u?TD ???o`??so_clock_gettime__vdso_gettimeofday__vdso_time__vdso_getcpulinux-vdso.so.1LINUX_2.6???
^
 ???o???o???o?Linux?GNUc??ݎ#?\?,?<j^?????8?T?|L?\?,DLdzRx
Y                                                       $0#A?C
?
A
 D?
l $D8?A?P
?
A
 I?
  Ll?E

vpKv`vx
  vhEvXN
?B?

B?B?B?A?D
        A
         L?`?E

vpKv`vx
  vhEvX?
?B?

B?B?B?A?D
        A

F?       ?A?M
`??*A?H
i???L?b???H??΃???p???t_??1H?? H]??Z???H+??????I????I???H???ҋ8???IH?H??H?? H????A9?u?H?H9????HC|???]?1??]??L?TH???A??A?r?UH??AVAUATARL?m?SH?8???H????tq???tC???????mH?Z???H?H?X???H?;u?1?H??[AZA\A]A^]I?b????u?H????H?H????H?;t????D?#A??u???????E?H?????D9#u?L??H??H=?ɚ;v*1?H-ʚ;??H=?ɚ;w?HH??E̅??g???????1??I???H?u??j???H?u?H+?????????H#????H??I??H?u??@???H?u?H+]????g???H#XW?????1D?E9?t$D?E??u??E?1??H??????????u???H?? H??I??H??H?H???? ?????H?? H    ?I??H??H?H?????????o????f.?L?TH???A?r?UH??AVAUATARSH??H????L?%"???L?m?H??E?$A???7?
????E;$u?L??H??H???ɚ;??1?H??ʚ;??H???ɚ;w?H?E?H?????H??H???S㥛? H??H??H??H?1?H????H??[AZA\A]A^]I?b??H?u??)???H?u?H+F????P?????????1ED9?tWA?8??u??E?1??H?u?L???????H?u??1??8?????????)?????%????V?T????`H???E???H?? H   ?I??H??H?H????K????@f.?UH??H?????H??tH?]Ð??????????U?{H????H??t
????H??t??
????rK???wq>???mr???cq????Yr!???Oq???Er????;q????1r]???'???????????????????????GCC: (GNU) 7.3.1 20180712 (Red Hat 7.3.1-9).shstrtab.gnu.hash.dynsym.dynstr.gnu.version.gnu.version_d.dynamic.rodata.note.eh_frame_hdr.eh_frame.text.altinstructions.altinstr_replacement.comment  <
                              ???o``H
                                    ????^%???o??2???oAHJXXR??<X??p` `   ?vJJ????"?0?,'?H??`???????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????H?????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????
```

Does anyone have any idea what this means and how to debug?

Comment: Seems like binary file content that should be read by nginx back.

Comment: What do mean read by nginx? If this is a file dump....